# Azure and Traditional Hosting / Distributed and Traditional Auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, dotnetopenauth, federated-identity

In pursuit of building a ASP.NET MVC3 application-framework, I want to have an authentication mechanism that:

- Supports SSO / federated security such as through OAuth or OpenID.
- Also leaves room to support local accounts.
- Works in a traditional hosting environment or can leverage unique capabilities in Azure.
- Avoids the [pitfalls of the MembershipProvider and SimpleMembership](http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/).
- Works with .net 4.5 / MVC 4
- Works with either Azure web roles or Azure web sites.
- BONUS: works with MVC 3

I don't think there is a single auth solution that addresses these goals.  It looks as though I can best achieve these goals if my web application-framework was configurable to use either of the following:

- [Access Control Service (ACS) version 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg429786.aspx), which enjoys [new "Identity and Access" Visual Studio 2012 tools](http://yorkporc.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/visual-studio-websso-with-mvc4-dotnet-4-5-identity-model-and-acs-v2/)
- [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/documentation/securityscenarios/) or perhaps [DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet](https://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet)

So my questions are these:

1. Is my plan to support both appropriate for my stated goals?  Or is it possible to use ACS to obtain all the goals?  For example, does ACS offer its own service-free "stand-alone" assembly(ies) that can play the same role as DotNetOpenAuth when used on a traditional hosting provider?
2. What are the configuration "points" and parts I will need to touch in order to easily enable either?

   1. Could this be done simply with XDT and transforming the web.config based on the build target?
   2. Does ACS use a recognizeable hook point, such as an HTTPModule, in order to redirect to an auth service - or does it use a deeper tool-set?

I just want to be sure my strategy for achieving the goals is fairly solid, and that I know what I'm getting myself into.  I'm also hoping that either approach will still work with the standard, claims-capable RolePrincipal.  This way my authorization mechanisms can be reserved for internal handling by my web application-framework.